# Problem using PHP to open text file - blank spaces are removed

Tags: php

I'm trying to open and process ASCII files using PHP, but am having problems. The problem 
is that the blank spaces are removed, which I don't want to have happen, since the files are fixed width.

The PHP script I used is this:

```
$myFile = Test.SEG";
$file_handler = fopen ($myFile, r) or die ("Can't open SEG File.");
while (!feof($file_handler))
    {
    $dataline = fgets($file_handler);
    echo $dataline, "<br />";
    }
```

I tried pasting samples of the original file in here, but the spaces were removed here as well!

At this stage I'm just building the script in steps, getting one step working at a time, but this is as far as I've gotten. I plan to use substr() on '$dataline' to pick out the fields I need.

Any suggestions on how to keep the spaces intact? Something tells me it's something to do  with encoding, but I don't know for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: what does `var_dump(file_get_contents('Test.SEG'))` produce?

Comment: could you show sample text of your file?

Comment: *(reference)* http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space and http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/pre

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think they are really removed.  Try adding `<pre>` before and `</pre>` after to find out if they are really gone.  I think it is just the HTML rendering that makes them appear gone.

Comment: Or "view source" for the page to show actual unrendered output.

Comment: I wish I could downvote every answer which suggests wrapping non-HTML content in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Are you the drive-by down-voter then salathe? I'd prefer you explain your reasoning.

Comment: @erisco - Don't bother reasoning with idiots. OP is outputting to HTML, and using `<pre>` is the way this will ever work with HTML (outside of `&nbsp;` .. *shudder*). So your answer is fine.

Comment: @salathe:  I didn't recommend he use it permanently -- I suggested he try it to prove whether they are still there or not.  The code snippet provided is clearly just for troubleshooting purposes and would probably not be used in production.  Downvoting seems like a reasonable response only if you did not read my answer.

Comment: @erisco I've outlined this on previous questions/answers saying the same thing (not sure if SO allows searching of comments) — feel free to disagree and continue being happy using `<pre>`.  And yes, I did down-vote those answers in this thread, mostly for the parrot-factor... is that bad etiquette?

Comment: @Matt everyone is entitled to their opinions and I totally respect that, please respect mine rather than making petty quips about intelligence.

Comment: @MJB Of course you didn't recommend he use it permanently; quicky tips that provide basic debugging information (or in this case, clarity in what the values contain) are very helpful, no denying that.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I'll digest and try all of this, and I know you guys have me on the right track.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to not read in the blank spaces.. MJB is exactly right. Html will only show one space no matter how many you have. (unless it is preformatted using teh <pre></pre> tags)

Comment: @salathe when the question first goes up multiple people click on it and start answering simultaneously. My answer was submitted roughly at the same time as the other four. I had no way avoid giving a similar answer before I had already put the effort in.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with encoding, and everything with the fact that your browser is treating the output as HTML. Either send a header to have the browser treat it as `text/plain`, or put it in a `<pre>` block.

Answer (score 0):

Browser won't care about more than one space, but if you see the source, you will see the correct output.
If I understand correctly, you should replace all the space chars with 'nbsp' for example.

Edited: pre is better as someone wrote here

Comment: Thanks, I'll try replacing ' ' with '& nbsp' as I see below.

Answer (score 0):

A browser will not preserve whitespace when rendering text on an HTML page. Consequently, newlines and tabs are ignored while multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space.

If you view the source of your page you can see the original whitespace. A `<pre>` block will tell the browser to preserve the whitespace when displaying the text on the page. Take this example:

```
this is   just


a test
of   some

    data.
```

I tested your code locally and there seem to be a few mistakes in it.

```
<?php

$myFile = "Test.SEG"; // missing opening quote

$file_handler = fopen($myFile, "r") // missing quotes for read mode flag
                or die ("Can't open SEG File.");

while (!feof($file_handler)) {
  $dataline = fgets($file_handler);
  echo $dataline; // fgets keeps the newline,
                  // so you do not need to output another
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll fix what needs fixing. And you're right - the html source has the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without the space between "&" and "nbsp;"):

```
echo str_replace(' ', '& nbsp;', $dataline)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override pre tag css , **white-space: pre-line**