# The result of "echo fgets()" in a txt file is not the same

Tags: php, html, fgets

I am trying to include in my website a txt file with php using the following code

```
    <?php 
      $myFile = '[http://users.otenet.gr/~vag1976/optonio/NOAAMO.TXT]';
      $fp = fopen("$myFile", "r");
      while(!feof($fp)) { 
        echo fgets($fp) . "<br />";
      }
      fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

The problem is that using this php code the result is not exactly the same as the original. The gaps (spaces) between the words are lost and are replaced by only one space. The viewing result is terrible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a PHP problem, it's just the browser which does not render multiple 'normal' spaces (if you don't use non-breaking-spaces `&nbsp;` or the special `<pre>` tag).

You should also use a real line feed instead of `<br />` tags:

```
<?php 
  $myFile = '[http://users.otenet.gr/~vag1976/optonio/NOAAMO.TXT]';
  // You don't need to use "$myFile" here, just use the variable without quotes
  $fp = fopen($myFile, "r");
  echo "<pre>";
  while(!feof($fp)) { 
    echo fgets($fp) . "\n";
  }
  echo "</pre>";
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

If your file is not too large, you can also use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
<?php
  $myFile = '[http://users.otenet.gr/~vag1976/optonio/NOAAMO.TXT]';
  echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($myFile) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write around it some `<pre>`-tags:

```
<pre><?php /* your code */ ?></pre>
```

`<pre>` preserves whitespaces.

A browser always replaces multiple following whitespaces by one single.

Then you can also use `\n` instead of `<br />` for doing your line wraps.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the spaces use `<pre></pre>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `<pre>` tag. It preserves excess whitespace.

```
<?php 
  $myFile = '[http://users.otenet.gr/~vag1976/optonio/NOAAMO.TXT]';
  $fp = fopen("$myFile", "r"); 
  echo "<pre>";
  while(!feof($fp)) { 
    echo fgets($fp) . "<br />";
  }
  echo "</pre>"; 
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

Also, I hope you realize `<br />` isn't HTML5 semantics-enriched linguistics.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you need to enclose whatever you return with `fgets()` in a `<pre>` tag to preserve the whitespace.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805900/2305229

Modified code:

```
<?php 
  $myFile = '[http://users.otenet.gr/~vag1976/optonio/NOAAMO.TXT]';
  $fp = fopen("$myFile", "r");
  while(!feof($fp)) { 
    echo "<pre>";
    echo fgets($fp) . "<br />";
    echo "</pre>"
  }
  fclose($fp);
?>
```